# Orchard multiple cultures

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchard-modules

I have site working on orchard CMS. Site has 2 cultures : en-Us and ru-RU. All pages has translations. For example page has path

> http://examplesite.com/{culture}/company-contacts

where culture en or ru.
But i see in browser, that waiting of responce (html) fo ru culture in 2 times bigger than fo en culture.
Waiting for ru-945 ms and for en -430 ms. All ru pages slowwer than en pages.
Content Localization module and Content Picker module are enabled.
orchard version 1.10.2

Comment: Which of the two is set as the default site language in your settings? Is 945 ms the time it takes just to get a response from the server or to fully display the page, including all styles and scripts?

Comment: Default culture is en-US. But when I change default culture on ru-RU, result is the same. 945 ms - response from the server.